# Why do I get the error "expressions must have one parent element", how do I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm relatively new to React and I'm wondering what's the standard here.

Imagine I have a react-router like this one:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="home component={Home} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
      <Route path="contacts" component={Contacts} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

And now I want to remove two routes if `prop.mail` is set to `false`, so a sane way of doing that would look like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="home component={Home} />
        <Route path="about" component={About} />

        { if.this.props.mail ? 
          <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
          <Route path="contacts" component={Contacts} />
        : null }

      </Route>
 </Router>
```

But there are 2 routes and React returns error:

> expressions must have one parent element.

I don't want to use multiple ifs here. What's the preferred React way of handling this?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Put them in an array (assign the keys also):

```
{ if.this.props.mail ? 
    [
        <Route key={0} path="inbox" component={Inbox} />,
        <Route key={1} path="contacts" component={Contacts} />
    ]
: null }
```

With latest React version, you can try **[`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)** also, like this:

```
{ if.this.props.mail ? 
    <React.Fragment>
        <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />,
        <Route path="contacts" component={Contacts} />
    </React.Fragment>
: null }
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why, but arrays never worked for me - it always returned the same error.

Comment: For those who have the same error in react native... you probably have multiple elements in the ternary like this: 
`{ this.state.isEnabled 
? 
<Text>Hello World</Text><Text>I am here</Text> 
:
 <Text>Hello World</Text><Text>I am on my way</Text>
} ` 
So all you need to do is put the elements into a 
`{this.state.isEnabled 
? 
<View><Text>Hello World</Text><Text>I am here</Text></View> 
:
 <View><Text>Hello World</Text><Text>I am on my way</Text></View>
}`
 Hope this helps

Comment: Nice !! I had this error and wasnt understanding why. Its due to the way you're suppose to return elements. Thanks for pointing fragment !

Comment: What would the complete code look like? I'm not sure how to take this fragment and add it as a child of the parent element.

Comment: NOTE! React.Fragment is a bit tricky. If you have another route after the fragment, it may not catch it. Check this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6953

Answer (score 49):

You can leverage [short hand fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax) to return a list of children along with [Logical '&&' Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) for conditional rendering. Nice and clean!

```js
{this.props.mail && 
  <>
    <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
    <Route path="contacts" component={Contacts} />
  </>
}
```

Comment: the , is not necessary, correct?

Comment: Thanks for flagging @EinEsellesEniE. Updated!

Answer (score 16):

You must been use a fragment tag e.g(div, <>,...).

Check this short solution:

```
{ if.this.props.mail ? 
 <>
   <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox} />
   <Route path="contacts" component={Contacts} />
 </>
 : null }
```

Comment: You just saved my life! Tried to implement NextJS's Image component and got this error. Wrapping the Image<> inside `<> ... </>` fixed the issue!

Answer (score 6):

just try enclosing the code after the return statement in an element like `<div>....code </div>`,etc.

eg:-

```
const Div =()=>{
           return
            <div>
              <Button name="Save" ></Button>
              <Button name="Edit"></Button>
              <Button name="Cancel"></Button>  
            </div>}
```

Answer (score 4):

**2020 update**

I have checked out every solution from answers. Here is the breakdown for regular React:

**1. React Fragment**

When i wanted to use it once, without adding additional DOM node - it worked. When i tried to use second React.Fragment got really bad errors. Wasn't able to fix it.

**2. View**

I was unable to import View properly. I don't know if this is only for Reactjs, or Native, but this does not work

**3. Div**

What actually worked was to put HTML into Div

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same error in a similar situation (React Native).

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      <AppContainer />
    );
  }
}
```

As indicated in the error prompt the JSX expression requires to have one parent element, hence wrap the elements in the return expression with a parent element. The `flex: 1` style was added to allow the `<View>` element assume the height of the entire screen.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
        <AppContainer />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks. Worth noting that it requires an "import View from 'react-view-component/lib/View';"

Comment: To add on, if we are talking normal React then you'd just want to wrap the above code in a div to prevent this error.  Example:
`export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <div>

        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />

        <AppContainer />

      </div>

    );

  }

}`

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me.

<React.Fragment>
……..
</React.Fragment>

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `<Switch>`, then using `<div>` and `<React.Fragment>` to wrap your routes will break it.

I like the idea of a `<ProtectedRoute>` component:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class ProtectedRoute extends Component<any> {
  render() {
    const { component: Component, allow, ...props } = this.props;
    if (!allow) {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/signin' }} />;
    }
    return <Route {...props} render={(props) => <Component {...props} />} />;
  }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Then use it like below:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />

    <ProtectedRoute path="inbox" component={Inbox} allow={this.props.mail} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="contacts" component={Contacts} allow={this.props.mail} />

  </Route>
</Router>
```