# Getting error while adding buttons using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error while adding two extra button in the list using React.js.

> Error:

```
./src/TodoItems.js
Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (10:46)
   8 |  
   9 |   createTasks(item) {
> 10 |     return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li><a href="" class="button bg_green">Edit</a><a href=""class="button bg_red">Delete</a>
     |                                               ^
  11 |   }
  12 |  
  13 |   render() {
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class TodoItems extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.createTasks = this.createTasks.bind(this);
  }

  createTasks(item) {
    return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li><a href="" class="button bg_green">Edit</a><a href=""class="button bg_red">Delete</a>
  }

  render() {
    var todoEntries = this.props.entries;
    var listItems = todoEntries.map(this.createTasks);

    return (
      <ul className="theList">
          {listItems}
      </ul>
    );
  }
};

export default TodoItems;
```

Here I am adding two button with the list `i.e-li element` and getting the above error. I need to resolve those error and add two button there.

Comment: first thing first, use `className` instead of `class` in `JSX`, and use a `()`  to wrap your `JSX` after the `return`

Comment: @izengod : I did like `return <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li><a href="" className="button bg_green" key={item.key}>Edit</a><a href=""className="button bg_red" key={item.key}>Delete</a>
    ()` but same error.

Comment: createTasks must return a parent element, like <li key={item.key}>{item.text} <a href="" className="button bg_green" key={item.key>Edit</a><a href=""className="button bg_red" key={item.key>Delete</a></li>   or wrap it under a div ... check this below : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ypqryi

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Possible duplicate [React - expressions must have one parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886726/react-expressions-must-have-one-parent-element)

Comment: Glad, you got what you need @subhra . For finding out this type ff errors check with some online IDE's for react like stackblitz.com, this will show an error immediately before posting on stackoverflow. You could solve it urself

Answer (score 2):

```
import { Fragment } from 'react'

 createTasks(item) {
return 
       <Fragment>
            <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li>
            <a href="" class="button bg_green">Edit</a>
            <a href=""class="button bg_red">Delete</a>
       </Fragment>
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to create a list wiche should look in pure HTML like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
      Some Text
      <a href="" class="button bg_green">Edit</a>
      <a href=""class="button bg_red">Delete</a>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

When you want to return a multiple components you need to wrap them inside a parent note. In this case you can use the `li` tag to have the correct semantic of you html. Additionaly you need to change the key word `class` to `className`.

```
createTasks(item) {
    return (
        <li key={item.key}>
            {item.text}
            <a href="" className="button bg_green">Edit</a>
            <a href=""className="button bg_red">Delete</a>
        </li>
    )
}

render() {
    var todoEntries = this.props.entries;
    var listItems = todoEntries.map(this.createTasks);

    return (
        <ul className="theList">
            {listItems}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

## Working Example

```js
class TodoItems extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.createTasks = this.createTasks.bind(this);
  }

  createTasks(item) {
    console.log(item)
    return (
        <li key={item.key}>
            {item.text}
            <a href="" className="button bg_green">Edit</a>
            <a href=""className="button bg_red">Delete</a>
        </li>
    )
  }

  render() {
    var todoEntries = this.props.entries;
    var listItems = todoEntries.map(this.createTasks);
    return (
      <ul className="theList">
          {listItems}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

const entries = [
   {
      key: 1,
      text: "Lern some Vanila JavaScript"
   },
   {
      key: 2,
      text: "Lern some React"
   }
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <TodoItems entries={entries}/>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap returned value in **createTasks** method:

```
  createTasks(item) {
    return 
           <div>
                <li key={item.key}>{item.text}</li>
                <a href="" class="button bg_green">Edit</a>
                <a href=""class="button bg_red">Delete</a>
           </div>
  }
```

Comment: Error gone but after submitting the li values are not displaying with both  buttons.

Comment: I would suggest using `<React.Fragment>` instead of `<div>` - OP is constructing a list (see `<ul> ... <li>` in the DOM), and having divs as immediate children of ul wouldn't be a valid HTML.

Comment: about to write this as comment. check this out https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html