# Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'

Tags: css, reactjs, dom, tsx

I'm trying to add this simple `div` to the return block of my .tsx file:

```
<div id="bizible.reportUser" style="display:none" data-email="some@email.com"/>
```

I do it the following way:

```
import React from 'react';
import Radium from 'radium';

import Icon from './Icon';
import Header from './Header';

import Colors from '../colors';

const NoMatch = ({ children, title, icon, kind }) => {
  return ([
    <div style={[styles.base, kind && styles[kind]]}>
      <Icon name={icon} style={[styles.icon]} height="48" width="48" />
      <Header title={title} style={[styles.header]} />
      <p style={[styles.message]}>
        {children}
      </p>
    </div>,
    <div id="bizible.reportUser" style="display:none" data-email="some@email.com"/>
  ]
  );
};
```

But it returns an Error message and does not compile:

```
error TS2322: Type '({children, title, icon, kind}: { children: any; title: any; icon: any; kind: any; }) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<Props>'.
  Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'.
    Property 'type' is missing in type 'Element[]'.
```

Comment: You are returning an array. Does it work if you just keep the `()`? I.e from `([ ... ])` to `()`.

Comment: no it doesn't @Tholle. It demands an array, otherwise you get this error: "JSX expressions must have one parent element."

Comment: That doesn't sound right. E.g. [the way stateless components are written here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html#write-some-code) works fine.

Comment: Last version of Reacts apparently requires the array notation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886726/react-expressions-must-have-one-parent-element

Comment: Yes, that's a fine way of writing it if you don't want to return just a single element, but you are returning a single `div` as the topmost element, so there is no need for an array is this case.

Comment: No, I'm returning two divs. But still, that doesn't fix the issue

Comment: You're right, I'm blind. Sorry about that. Have you tried wrapping it in a [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) instead of an array?

Answer (score 8):

You can always wrap the return value with `<React.Fragment>` (or `<>`). This will solve your problem without adding anything to the DOM.

Comment: Is this the best / only solution? I have the same issue saying: `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement'` after upgrading to React 18

Comment: @Tobiq this is not related... this solution won't fix your problem.