# Trying to use two props in the use defined component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I am adding two props (textProp & imgProp) to my custom component, but I keep on getting this error `JSX expression must have one parent element`. This is what I have soo far

```
function TextImg(textprop, imgprop) {
          return(
              <Text>{textprop.text}</Text>
              <Image source={imgprop.imageUri}></Image>
          );
  }
```

I tried using div, but this doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must only ever return _one_ react element. Consider wrapping Text and Image in a Fragment? https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - expressions must have one parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886726/react-expressions-must-have-one-parent-element)

Comment: Whoever voted your question down should undo that. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap this section in a React.Fragment

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Text>{textprop.text}</Text>
  <Image source={imgprop.imageUri}></Image>
</React.Fragment>
```

JSX needs a container like this

Comment: Then there's the problem with the props. :-)

Comment: @Ishasharmax - Awesome. I am also just starting with React. Good luck there. Accepting the answer ill close the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems there:

1. Your component receives a **single** argument, which is an object with properties for the props.
2. Your component must return a single element, single string, `undefined` or `null`, or a fragment; it can't return two elements without some kind of wrapper around them.

So:

```
function TextImg({textprop, imgprop}) {
//               ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− destructuring the object
    return <>
        <Text>{textprop.text}</Text>
        <Image source={imgprop.imageUri}></Image>
    </>;
}
```

Note the `<>` and `</>` denoting the fragment. (You can also use `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>`.)

Or without destructuring:

```
function TextImg(props) {
    return <>
        <Text>{props.textprop.text}</Text>
        <Image source={props.imgprop.imageUri}></Image>
    </>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, there are 2 issues going on in your code.

Functional Component is just a function which accepts one parameter which is called props.

But usually to make code easier to read, it was **destructured** into specific prop properties.

Therefore, instead of

```
function TextImg(props) {
```

people write it with

```
function TextImg({textprop, imgprop}) {
```

Another one is when returning it needs to be returned one tag to render.
Therefore, it can be returned with

```
return <div>
        <Text>{props.textprop.text}</Text>
        <Image source={props.imgprop.imageUri}></Image>
    </div>;
```

Instead of div, `<></>` or `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>` can be used to reduce DOM element.