# Error: error: Expected ',', got 'className' in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

> Error: error: Expected ',', got 'className' in nextjs

I'm trying to make a sign-in page using bootstrap 4, but it shows above error after compiling.

It shows error on 15 line of div tag

```
    return (

        <Head>
            <title>Sign in</title>
        </Head>
        <form>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">

                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>

                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" className="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" />
                <label className="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form> 
    )
}

export default signin
```

Comment: The code provided seems unrelated to the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - expressions must have one parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886726/react-expressions-must-have-one-parent-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReactJS doesn't allow 2 parent elements, make sure to use a div as parent element

```
return (
    <div>
        <Head>
            ...
        </Head> 
        <form> 
            ...
        </form> 
    </div>
 )
```

Comment: div or just React fragment: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: yeah, fragments work too, you can also use a shortcut for them by just using empty brackets `return <> ... </>`