# JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657) react error

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create the frontend of the application and keep getting the following error
Please help me
Here is my code.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <a href="/">amazona</a>
      </header>
      <main>
        <h1>Featured Products</h1>
        <div className="products">
          {data.products.map((product) => (
            <div className="product" key={product.slug}>
              <a href={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
                <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
              </a>
              <div className="product-info">
                <a href={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
                  <p>{product.name}</p>
                </a>
                <p>
                  <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                </p>
                <button>Add to cart</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <header>
          <Link to="/">amazona</Link>
        </header>
        <main>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/product/:slug" element={<ProductScreen />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. can you help me?

Comment: As it says, you're JSX needs a single parent element.  Wrap it all in a div or a fragment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get the error "expressions must have one parent element", how do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886726/why-do-i-get-the-error-expressions-must-have-one-parent-element-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your JSX return element into one Element. You are returning JSX.Element and not JSX.Element[]. All you need to do is wrap the return element into <></> like this:

```
   function App() {
     return (
       <>
        <div>
         <header>
           <a href="/">amazona</a>
         </header>
         <main>
           <h1>Featured Products</h1>
           <div className="products">
             {data.products.map((product) => (
               <div className="product" key={product.slug}>
                 <a href={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
                   <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
                 </a>
                 <div className="product-info">
                   <a href={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
                     <p>{product.name}</p>
                   </a>
                   <p>
                     <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                   </p>
                   <button>Add to cart</button>
                 </div>
               </div>
             ))}
           </div>
         </main>
       </div>
       <BrowserRouter>
         <div>
           <header>
             <Link to="/">amazona</Link>
           </header>
           <main>
             <Routes>
               <Route path="/product/:slug" element={<ProductScreen />} />
               <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
             </Routes>
           </main>
         </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
      </>
     );
   }
```